# f5_cspm script and content security policy

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

I have a web page which is injecting a f5_cspm script, identified using a nonce tag.

Also in the page, I have another script to set the use of this script based on that nonce value.

Unfortunately I am seeing an error in the browser console.

I will post some of the page below, but I am not sure what is relevant so if more information is required, please let me know.

Security policy being set:

cpsm script:

```
<script id="f5_cspm" nonce="iSEhvNsGAXkHj4T5u6VU1oBEU7qBrbA7"></script>
<script id="f5_cspm">(function(){var f5_cspm={f5_p:'FLDPMFDCIFBMEHADMAOHGNKOBBFOLMFOIMOKBJIFMJKBGMMKJICNMLPIANDANJEDAAIDEGIFLGCHEIKMAALCFPDKGHMOCCMLFIGFBOLKHIONEKNOLPJHLIPOGFMDPBCG',setCharAt:function(str,index,chr){if(index>str.length-1)return str;return str.substr(0,index)+chr+str.substr(index+1);},get_byte:function(str,i){var s=(i/16)|0;i=(i&15);s=s*32;return((str.charCodeAt(i+16+s)-65)<<4)|(str.charCodeAt(i+s)-65);},set_byte:function(str,i,b){var s=(i/16)|0;i=(i&15);s=s*32;str=f5_cspm.setCharAt(str,(i+16+s),String.fromCharCode((b>>4)+65));str=f5_cspm.setCharAt(str,(i+s),String.fromCharCode((b&15)+65));return str;},set_latency:function(str,latency){latency=latency&0xffff;str=f5_cspm.set_byte(str,32,(latency>>8));str=f5_cspm.set_byte(str,33,(latency&0xff));str=f5_cspm.set_byte(str,27,2);return str;},wait_perf_data:function(){try{var wp=window.performance.timing;if(wp.loadEventEnd>0){var res=wp.loadEventEnd-wp.navigationStart;if(res<60001){var cookie_val=f5_cspm.set_latency(f5_cspm.f5_p,res);window.document.cookie='f5avr1326886222aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa='+encodeURIComponent(cookie_val)+';path=/';}
return;}}
catch(err){return;}
setTimeout(f5_cspm.wait_perf_data,100);return;},go:function(){var chunk=window.document.cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/);for(var i=0;i<chunk.length;++i){var pair=chunk[i].split(/\s*=\s*/);if(pair[0]=='f5_cspm'&&pair[1]=='1234')
{var d=new Date();d.setTime(d.getTime()-1000);window.document.cookie='f5_cspm=;expires='+d.toUTCString()+';path=/;';setTimeout(f5_cspm.wait_perf_data,100);}}}}
f5_cspm.go();}());</script>
```

and finally, the error in the console:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-iSEhvNsGAXkHj4T5u6VU1oBEU7qBrbA7'". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.
```

My question is simple - how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Put the nonce attribute on the second script element (which actually contains the JavaScript) rather than putting the nonce attribute on the first script element (which is completely empty and doesn’t contain any JavaScript at all…)